# How can i add an item to a user in django (rest framework)

Tags: django

I have a Teammodel and a Usermodel.
Every User can belong to one or more Teams.
The creation of a user with a Team is working fine.
But i want to add a existing user to a existing Team.
I tried several options but for every option i get an error.

**The Models:**

```
class Teams(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   file = models.FileField(upload_to='team_icons', null='True', blank='True')
   members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='member')

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name

**The Serializers:**

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     member = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Teams.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields =['id', 'username', 'owner', 'password', 'todos','member', 'email', 'first_name', 
    'last_name',]
```

**The View**

class AddUserToTeam(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

```
queryset = models.User.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

So i want: user.member.add(x), x is the team where user had to be added to

Comment: You need to add the user from team example:
`myteam = Teams.objects.get(name='Myteam')`
`myteam.members.add(user)`

Comment: tx, its comming close, but a new Team is created with the user in it, i want the user added to an existing team.